# how to get all editext's value from ListItems in android and pass them to api

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext, listitem

I have made an activity in that one ListView is ther,In that ListView each listItem is having an editText named "qty",which can be edited,one textView is there which displays "price",I need is when i edit the edittext and if the entered value is more than some limi the textView value will change,After that i have to pass them as a parameter to an api as below:

```
http://yehki.epagestore.in/app_api/updateCart.php?customer_id=41&product_id=30&quantity=90&product_id=23&quantity=90
```

from that i will get subtotal's of eact item and have to set them to each item in the list,can anyone please help me for it?My code is as below..Please help me save my life...thank you

**main.java**

```
   package com.epe.yehki.ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epe.yehki.adapter.CartAdapter;
import com.epe.yehki.backend.BackendAPIService;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Pref;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class CartListActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Intent in = null;
    ListView lv;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> cartList;
    Bitmap bitmap;;
    private CartAdapter cartContent;
    JSONArray carts = null;
    ImageView back;
    TextView tv_place_order, tv_home;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_list);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_bak);
        tv_place_order = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_place_order);
        tv_home = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_home);
        cartList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        // execute the cartList api()...........!!!!
        new GetCartList().execute();
        // listView ClickEvent
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                lv.removeViewAt(position);
                cartContent.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        tv_home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                in = new Intent(CartListActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        tv_place_order.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * CART LIST PRODUCT LIST...............!!!!!!!!!
     */
    private class GetCartList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CartListActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Creating service handler class instance
            String cartUrl = Const.API_CART_LIST + "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(CartListActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "");
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(cartUrl, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_PRO_LIST)) {

                        carts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_PRO_LIST);
                        if (carts != null && carts.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts

                            for (int i = 0; i < carts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = carts.getJSONObject(i);

                                String proId = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID);
                                String proName = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                String wPrice = c.getString(Const.TAG_WHOLESALE_PRICE);
                                String rPrice = c.getString(Const.TAG_RETAIL_PRICE);
                                String qty = c.getString(Const.TAG_QUANTITY);
                                String proimg = Const.API_HOST + "/" + c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG);
                                HashMap<String, String> cartProduct = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_ID, proId);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, proName);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_IMG, proimg);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_WHOLESALE_PRICE, wPrice);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_RETAIL_PRICE, rPrice);
                                cartProduct.put(Const.TAG_QUANTITY, qty);

                                cartList.add(cartProduct);

                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * 
             * */

            cartContent = new CartAdapter(CartListActivity.this, cartList);
            lv.setAdapter(cartContent);

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: ues textwatcher on edit text when you can change value

Comment: use this edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText);
   // Capture Text in EditText
   edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { }

Comment: But i am confused so much because i have used adapter for ListView and each listItem having editexts so how to addtextwatcher,i dont know..:(

Answer (score 0):

In ListAdapter, getItem() should return an item using which you populate the Views

```
@Override
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int paramInt) {
    return cartArray.get(paramInt);
}
```

To get all values,

```
final CartAdapter adapter = (CardAdapter) lv.getAdapter();
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    final HashMap<String, String> item = adapter.getItem(i);
    final String quantity = item.get(Const.TAG_QUANTITY); // value of EditText of one row
}
```

Comment: can u tell me how to use it if i have to pass this values in to an url? means i have made an asynctask in that i have to use it.so code that you have give me .where should i place it?in DoInBackground?

Comment: it gives me error that listView can't be converted to adapter.

Comment: @Jigarjims I forgot to cast it to CartAdapter. Updated the answer. I'm  not sure what is your API so I can't tell you where to put the code. My answer just shows how to get values from ListAdapter.

Comment: Sir..I have updated my code...what i need is i want to send the "qty" editexts value from all the ListItems to another activity.can you tell me how to do that?